# Confusion over SSA axiom for congruency

Tags: triangles, angle, congruences-geometry

I was browsing through KHAN Academy videos when I met the one which Explained why SSA is not a Congruency postutate. But I had this Diagram in my Mind(Different from the video)

[Click Here to see diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp1DB.png)

Sorry that I cannot embed the image, as I have insufficient reputation

Here

> AC = PR, BC = QR, ANGLE A = ANGLE P

Now I feel that this information is enough to prove the Triangles congruent but my Book has no mention of it. Please Explain

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/congruentssa.html).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand that. But if the BASE is given(as in my case), is it incomplete

Comment: See Hypotenuse-Leg Theorem: The hypotenuse and a leg in a right triangle have the same length as those in another right triangle. This is also called RHS (right-angle, hypotenuse, side).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Are the Triangles in my figure congruent ?

Comment: If you consider a circle centered in $C$ with radius quite equal to $CA$ it will cut the semi-line starting from $A$ into two points $M_1$ and $M_2$. Obviously, $CM_1=CM_2$ and the two segment will belongs to two triangles satisying the SSA condition that are **not** congruent.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you explain in a little more detail

Comment: Take the point $C$ and draw the perpedicular to semi-line starting from $A$: call $M$ the intersection point. Now draw the circle with radius a "little bit" greater than $CM$: it will intersect the semi-line into two points: $M_1$ and $M_2$. Due to the fact that both lie on the circle, the two segments will be equal. Now consider the two triangles : $CAM_1$ and $CAM_2$ : they satisfy your "SSA criteris".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not.

See [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Similarity_and_congruence)

> "Side-Side-Angle condition: If two sides and a corresponding non-included angle of a triangle have the same length and measure, respectively, as those in another triangle, then this is not sufficient to prove congruence; but if the angle given is opposite to the longer side of the two sides, then the triangles are congruent. The Side-Side-Angle condition does not by itself guarantee that the triangles are congruent because one triangle could be obtuse-angled and the other acute-angled."

Regarding your drawing, you may consider a circle centered in $C$ with radius $CB$ : it will intersect the side $AB$ into $B_1$ with $CB=CB_1$.